# Common latent feature among all "memory techniques"

Tags: learning, memory, brain, brain-training

So I've been delving into "memory techniques" and people who compete in memory competitions(memorizing and reciting a poem in a small amount of time, memorizing a deck of cards, memorizing pi, etc). I've read books written by competitors as well as blogs in the community and have up with this list of techniques that are generally accepted as used in a competitive setting.

- Memory Palace: You allocate what you're trying to memorize into a visualization of a place you are familiar with
- Pegging: You link one piece of information to another by getting an association even if the two subjects are not related(memorizing your grocery list by remembering your first item in the list is "pickle" and that rhymes with "sickle" which is used to cut grain so you deduce the 2nd item is "rice")
- Projecting: A method used by some to memorize poems or story is to place themselves in it and see it firsthand in their mind

These are just a couple examples to prove a theory. My theory is all memory techniques are just spreading new knowledge across many neurons. In theory our brain works by when a neuron fires off, adjacent neurons fire off and we remember something.

So my theory is that all memory techniques just exploit this by embedding new knowledge into a breadth of neurons. Any thoughts or opinions on this? What makes a good "memory strategy" that is supported by what we know about the human brain?